# async and await return type confusion

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, windows-8, async-await

Hello friends i wanted to know the affects of return type of some async method on its behavior like i have one method called methodasync1() like

```
private async void methodasync1(filename)
{
    await getfileaysnc(filename);
}
```

and other function methodasync2() like

```
private async Task methodasync2(filename)
{
    await getfileasync(filename);
}
```

are both functions work in same way or there is any difference. 
and also any concept i should know plz tell me any idea and help is appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When a methods return type is void, it cannot be awaited, it's essentially a "fire and forget". So the method that calls methodasync1 in your case, has no way of knowing when it's actually completed. In the second case, methodasync2, since you're returning a Task, it CAN be awaited, so the calling method could know when it's actually done.

Comment: Also, the error handling is quite different. Exceptions from `async Task` methods are placed on the returned `Task`, but exceptions from `async void` methods are thrown directly on the `SynchronizationContext` that was current at the beginning of the method. I describe this more in my [article on `async` best practices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx).